# Dragging Menu for different Activities on Android

Tags: android, menu, drag

I need help finding an approach to build a certain kind of menu for an app.

Let's say I have a menu activity and 2 other activities. My menu activity consists of 2 options.
 I want to drag the "buttons" (not sure if button is the correct name in this case) sideways and while dragging, the other activity's screen starts appearing from the side.
 The thing is, depending on which button I'm dragging, different screens should appear, and I couldn't find anything similar to read about.
 Does anybody recommend some topic to read that could help?

How can I manage the activities in this case?

Comment: Looks like your tasks involves lots of customized UI development. First you have to implements that "button" that allow you to drag sideway. Then you can try to launch an activity depending on the button that you drag, and you may or may not have to implements a customized animation for the activity appearance also. So what have you done so far?

Comment: You ask very general question but base on my guess what you want to do I think you should read about Fragments. In short: fragment is a part of GUI, which can be added to different activity.

Comment: I had clickable buttons that would start the other activities and was asked to change it to this dragging style (just for aesthetics) and since I had no idea where to start by, I was asking before getting anything done.

Reading about fragments now, I guess that's what I need to learn.